# "My Location" in Google Maps javascript API

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to use the "My location" button that exist on [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com/) in your own webbapplication using the javascript api?
I have read about adding controls here [Google Maps Javascript API V3 Controls](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/controls.html) but I haven't found anything about the "My locaton" control.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's currently no geolocation button in Google Maps API v3. But it's not difficult to implement one yourself.

Information about implementing geolocation can be found in the [Google Maps Javascript API documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html#Geolocation).

If you want to add a geolocation button as a map control, read the [Custom Controls section](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls) of the Google Maps documentation.

Comment: That was what I feared. I don't have enough time to implement it myself. Oh well, it wasn't a must have function. Thanks for the answer.