# Show My Location on Google Maps API v3

Tags: html, google-maps-api-3

["My Location" in Google Maps javascript API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962085/my-location-in-google-maps-javascript-api)

This question was asked over half a year ago. Has Google Maps API v3 updated to use the "My Location" button found on http://maps.google.com?

My Location is the control between the Street View man and the gamepad-looking controls.

If Google Maps API doesn't provide My Location then do I need to write my own HTML5 geolocation feature using `navigator.gelocation` then create my own control on Google Maps?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

[No](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html), but adding your own marker based on current location is easy:

```
var myloc = new google.maps.Marker({
    clickable: false,
    icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage('//maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/mobile/mobileimgs2.png',
                                                    new google.maps.Size(22,22),
                                                    new google.maps.Point(0,18),
                                                    new google.maps.Point(11,11)),
    shadow: null,
    zIndex: 999,
    map: // your google.maps.Map object
});

if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
        var me = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
        myloc.setPosition(me);
    }, function(error) {
        // ...
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up creating a custom control and adding a click listener. When the listener triggered it pretty much did what you typed: add a marker to the user's location.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Nevertheless, if you use this, you might want to download the image hosted at [link](maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/mobile/mobileimgs2.png) and save it locally in your server. If this isn't done, you are always depending on another server's connection plus yours. By downloading the image, everything should work even smoother

Comment: To be fair, that's a Google server.  If it is down, the Maps API isn't working either.

Comment: But how do you redraw the location icon when the user moves? In my case, it just creates a new one each time

Comment: You can simplyfy to `icon : 'path/to/icon.png'`

Answer (score 5):

We have made such a component for Google Maps API v3. Anybody can use in custom projects to add a control showing current geolocation with just one line of code:

```
var geoloccontrol = new klokantech.GeolocationControl(map, mapMaxZoom);
```

after including in the HTML header this JavaScript:

```
<script src="https://cdn.klokantech.com/maptilerlayer/v1/index.js"></script>
```

See:

http://www.maptiler.com/maptilerlayer/

for an example code and documentation.

[image: Show My Location Control on Google Maps API v3]

It adds the standard control to the map - and once tapped - it shows the blue circle around your location with size derived from precision of the location data available. If you don't drag the map it will keep you positioned once you move.

This control has been developed for viewer automatically generated by http://www.maptiler.com/ software - which creates tiles for map overlays and custom layers made from images and raster geodata.

Comment: Somehow the GeolocationControl doesn't show up for me (even when I use the exact same code from the docs). All the other functionality of the library does work for me. Are there known issues regarding that button?

Comment: Geo location icon not displaying after including ` 
var geoloccontrol = new klokantech.GeolocationControl(map, mapMaxZoom);

<script src="https://cdn.klokantech.com/maptilerlayer/v1/index.js"></script>` in my file

Comment: I changed "var geoloccontrol = new klokantech.GeolocationControl(map, mapMaxZoom);" to "var geoloccontrol = new klokantech.GeolocationControl(map);" and it worked. Basically I removed the uninitialized optional opt_zoom parameter. Alternatively you could just replace 'mapMaxZoom' with an actual value which would be the zoom level the map will switch to once the initial location is acquired. Now, does anyone know how to override the default 'my location' button size? It's quite small compared to the new Google Maps API that was recently reworked to have larger UI buttons.

Comment: Everything works fine when I see the map in a browser, BUT i do not get the same result when I build an android mobile app using Apache Cordova, why? The problem is that although I use exactly the same code as the one on the browser, the button is not visible, is there another way round to continuously show the current position in a Apache Cordova mobile app? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

you have to do it by your own. Here is a piece of code to add "Your Location" button.
**HTML**

```
<div id="map">Map will be here</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#map {width:100%;height: 400px;}
```

**JS**

```
var map;
var faisalabad = {lat:31.4181, lng:73.0776};

function addYourLocationButton(map, marker) 
{
    var controlDiv = document.createElement('div');

    var firstChild = document.createElement('button');
    firstChild.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    firstChild.style.border = 'none';
    firstChild.style.outline = 'none';
    firstChild.style.width = '28px';
    firstChild.style.height = '28px';
    firstChild.style.borderRadius = '2px';
    firstChild.style.boxShadow = '0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3)';
    firstChild.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    firstChild.style.marginRight = '10px';
    firstChild.style.padding = '0px';
    firstChild.title = 'Your Location';
    controlDiv.appendChild(firstChild);

    var secondChild = document.createElement('div');
    secondChild.style.margin = '5px';
    secondChild.style.width = '18px';
    secondChild.style.height = '18px';
    secondChild.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://maps.gstatic.com/tactile/mylocation/mylocation-sprite-1x.png)';
    secondChild.style.backgroundSize = '180px 18px';
    secondChild.style.backgroundPosition = '0px 0px';
    secondChild.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
    secondChild.id = 'you_location_img';
    firstChild.appendChild(secondChild);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {
        $('#you_location_img').css('background-position', '0px 0px');
    });

    firstChild.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var imgX = '0';
        var animationInterval = setInterval(function(){
            if(imgX == '-18') imgX = '0';
            else imgX = '-18';
            $('#you_location_img').css('background-position', imgX+'px 0px');
        }, 500);
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                marker.setPosition(latlng);
                map.setCenter(latlng);
                clearInterval(animationInterval);
                $('#you_location_img').css('background-position', '-144px 0px');
            });
        }
        else{
            clearInterval(animationInterval);
            $('#you_location_img').css('background-position', '0px 0px');
        }
    });

    controlDiv.index = 1;
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(controlDiv);
}

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 15,
        center: faisalabad
    });
    var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: faisalabad
    });
    addYourLocationButton(map, myMarker);
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    initMap();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//copy and paste this in your script section.
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
} else {
    alert('location not supported');
}

//callbacks
function error(msg) {
    alert('error in geolocation');
}

function success(position) {
    var lats = position.coords.latitude;
    var lngs = position.coords.longitude;
    alert(lats);
    alert(lngs)
};
```

Comment: This geolocation example doesn't even show any google maps code.