# google maps setting of my location

Tags: javascript, google-maps

```
var myloc;
function initialize() {

  if (navigator.geolocation) navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
    var me = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
    myloc.setPosition(me);
    myloc.setMap(map);
  }, function(error) {
      // ...
  });

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: me,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var mylocOptions = {
    title: "You are here..."
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), 
      mapOptions);

  myloc = new google.maps.Marker(mylocOptions);
}
```

I checked out [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142833/show-my-location-on-google-maps-api-v3) and feel like I got somewhere with this.  When I open the app (the first time) it asks me for permission to use my location.  I think I simplified the myloc options, I'm fine with the default look and everything of the marker for testing.  Upon allowing it, nothing happens, though.  `me is undefined`.  Maybe I'm doing something in the wrong order?

Without the location, I am able to get the map up with other markers, so... it's gotta be an order thing?  I've tried a few variations...

I'd like to eventually plop a marker onto the map after the browser gives up the general coordinates.  Eventually that will be movable and updated in the db, but I'm not worried about that just yet, obviously.  Baby steps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set your marker's position to me when you first initialize it. Because `me` is available after the user allows the browser to use their location. Do it when you get their location.

```
var mylocOptions = {
  title: "You are here..."
};

if (navigator.geolocation) navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
  var me = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
  myloc.setPosition(me);
  myloc.setMap(map);
  map.setCenter(me);
}, function(error) {
  // ...
});
```

also remove

```
center: me
```

where you define `map`.

Comment: modified... Uncaught ReferenceError: me is not defined.  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setPosition' of undefined

Comment: something is working, because I have the cool little target thing in my browser, showing me that the site is tracking my position.  but, alas...

Comment: but myloc is defined outside of the `initialize()` function, no?

Comment: tried it, get `me is not defined` only, now.  also lost the location marker in the browser when I put it below the `myloc = mew~`

Comment: also remove `center: me`. as i said, `me` is only available after user allows. see my updated answer

Comment: nope, my bad!  you got it!  i didn't see that you edited the `setCenter(me)`.  didn't even have to move it below the `myloc=~`.  thank you so much!!