# How to add my location button in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'd like to know if it's possible to add as default controls option ***my location*** button.

[image: map with my location button]

Is there any way to make it as default or I need to make button with geolocation and then trigger the click event on that button in order to navigate user to the current location?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We have made such a component for Google Maps API v3. Anybody can use in custom projects to add a control showing current geolocation with just one line of code:

```
var geoloccontrol = new klokantech.GeolocationControl(map, mapMaxZoom);
```

after including in the HTML header this JavaScript:

```
<script src="https://cdn.klokantech.com/maptilerlayer/v1/index.js"></script>
```

See:

http://www.maptiler.com/maptilerlayer/

for an example code and documentation.

[image: Show My Location Control on Google Maps API v3]

It adds the standard control to the map - and once tapped - it shows the blue circle around your location with size derived from precision of the location data available. If you don't drag the map it will keep you positioned once you move.

This control has been developed for viewer automatically generated by http://www.maptiler.com/ software - which creates tiles for map overlays and custom layers made from images and raster geodata.

Note: this answer is a repost of our response from [Show My Location on Google Maps API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142833/show-my-location-on-google-maps-api-v3)

Comment: Yap, that's great! I've just update your answer as solution since the it comes out that we have ready component instead of customizing.

Comment: Great, except the handling of BOTTOM_RIGHT position for the controller is totally broken. I've just sent you a bug report, it's a shame that apparently it's not tracked publicly. Do you know of any workaround?

Comment: how to use this in react js?

Answer (score 64):

As [@Praveen said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24959465/792888), you have to do it on your own. Here is a piece of code to add a "Your Location" button.

[JS fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/mi3afzal/ogsvzacz/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="map">Map will be here</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#map {width:100%;height: 400px;}
```

**JS**

```
var map;
var faisalabad = {lat:31.4181, lng:73.0776};

function addYourLocationButton(map, marker) 
{
    var controlDiv = document.createElement('div');
    
    var firstChild = document.createElement('button');
    firstChild.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    firstChild.style.border = 'none';
    firstChild.style.outline = 'none';
    firstChild.style.width = '28px';
    firstChild.style.height = '28px';
    firstChild.style.borderRadius = '2px';
    firstChild.style.boxShadow = '0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3)';
    firstChild.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    firstChild.style.marginRight = '10px';
    firstChild.style.padding = '0px';
    firstChild.title = 'Your Location';
    controlDiv.appendChild(firstChild);
    
    var secondChild = document.createElement('div');
    secondChild.style.margin = '5px';
    secondChild.style.width = '18px';
    secondChild.style.height = '18px';
    secondChild.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://maps.gstatic.com/tactile/mylocation/mylocation-sprite-1x.png)';
    secondChild.style.backgroundSize = '180px 18px';
    secondChild.style.backgroundPosition = '0px 0px';
    secondChild.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
    secondChild.id = 'you_location_img';
    firstChild.appendChild(secondChild);
    
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() {
        $('#you_location_img').css('background-position', '0px 0px');
    });

    firstChild.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var imgX = '0';
        var animationInterval = setInterval(function(){
            if(imgX == '-18') imgX = '0';
            else imgX = '-18';
            $('#you_location_img').css('background-position', imgX+'px 0px');
        }, 500);
        if(navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                marker.setPosition(latlng);
                map.setCenter(latlng);
                clearInterval(animationInterval);
                $('#you_location_img').css('background-position', '-144px 0px');
            });
        }
        else{
            clearInterval(animationInterval);
            $('#you_location_img').css('background-position', '0px 0px');
        }
    });
    
    controlDiv.index = 1;
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(controlDiv);
}

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 15,
        center: faisalabad
    });
    var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: faisalabad
    });
    addYourLocationButton(map, myMarker);
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    initMap();
});
```

Comment: this approach made my solution look great

Comment: Fizal bhai, shukriya 
Very good solution and its working pretty much fine 
Jazakallah

Answer (score 27):

I've slightly amended mi3afzal's fiddle to drop the jQuery dependency and add retina support. Also, I suggest using the `center_changed` event rather then `dragend` as the center could be changed programatically, e.g. when adding markers and extending bounds.

https://jsfiddle.net/ogsvzacz/6/.

```js
var map,
    faisalabad = {lat:31.4181, lng:73.0776};

function addYourLocationButton (map, marker) 
{
    var controlDiv = document.createElement('div');

    var firstChild = document.createElement('button');
    firstChild.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    firstChild.style.border = 'none';
    firstChild.style.outline = 'none';
    firstChild.style.width = '28px';
    firstChild.style.height = '28px';
    firstChild.style.borderRadius = '2px';
    firstChild.style.boxShadow = '0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3)';
    firstChild.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    firstChild.style.marginRight = '10px';
    firstChild.style.padding = '0';
    firstChild.title = 'Your Location';
    controlDiv.appendChild(firstChild);

    var secondChild = document.createElement('div');
    secondChild.style.margin = '5px';
    secondChild.style.width = '18px';
    secondChild.style.height = '18px';
    secondChild.style.backgroundImage = 'url(https://maps.gstatic.com/tactile/mylocation/mylocation-sprite-2x.png)';
    secondChild.style.backgroundSize = '180px 18px';
    secondChild.style.backgroundPosition = '0 0';
    secondChild.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
    firstChild.appendChild(secondChild);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function () {
        secondChild.style['background-position'] = '0 0';
    });

    firstChild.addEventListener('click', function () {
        var imgX = 0,
            animationInterval = setInterval(function () {
                imgX = -imgX - 18 ;
                secondChild.style['background-position'] = imgX+'px 0';
            }, 500);

        if(navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                map.setCenter(latlng);
                clearInterval(animationInterval);
                secondChild.style['background-position'] = '-144px 0';
            });
        } else {
            clearInterval(animationInterval);
            secondChild.style['background-position'] = '0 0';
        }
    });

    controlDiv.index = 1;
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM].push(controlDiv);
}


map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 15,
  center: faisalabad
});
var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map: map,
  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
  position: faisalabad
});
addYourLocationButton(map, myMarker);
```

Comment: Thanks. Please add marker.setPosition(latlng) when current position is found.

Answer (score 23):

[*Google maps*](https://www.google.co.in/maps/preview) itself is a customized-implementation of their [**Google maps API**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/).  So you have to do it on your own.

AFIK *Google maps API v3* does not provide any default control for "show my location", however implementing your own is simple;

1. API v3 provides the ability add [**custom
   controls**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom)
   to maps so you can easily add the icon and write a event handler as
   mentioned below.
2. Use "HTML5 Geolocation", which returns you the position of your current location.
3. So make use the lat/lng and
       when you click icon process the it to place a [**marker**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple).

Comment: Thank a lot! I would check as it's solved! Actually I realized it during the night, it's really explained well!

Comment: Uptove for mentioning the relation between Google Maps API and Google Maps itself.

Answer (score 0):

For future needs, you can also consider using this simple library:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-current-location

It adds the typical button to the map, it handles the geolocation, and it also adds the blue circle surrounding the marker.