# How to enable "Display Images" control in a map?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I would like to enable "Display Images" control in a map, like below (from Google Maps default page):

[image]

But currently I have only the "pegman" icon, without a way to expand the image gallery:

[image]

The code for my map is:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>

(...)

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-30, -51),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);
```

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952593/how-to-add-my-location-button-in-google-maps

Comment: @adjuremods The location part is the same, but what I actually need most is the "photos" part. There was some "panoramio layer" some time ago, but it was disabled, even though the functionality still exists in Google Maps.