# My location layer in google maps doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, location, maps

My school assignment is to create a mobile first, website prototype (so NOT an application).
I would like to integrate google maps in the website - ,
[I've already put ground overlay in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iOZ7.png), but I would like to enable the "my location layer" as well. However, when I tried to insert *mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);* in the code, the my location button doesn't appear.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

    #map {
      height: 100%;
    }

    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">

var historicalOverlay;

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 17,
    center: {lat: 55.380, lng: 10.342652}
  });

  var imageBounds = {
    north: 55.384621,
    south: 55.376012,
    east: 10.3473,
    west: 10.333567
  };

  historicalOverlay = new google.maps.GroundOverlay(
      'map2.svg',
      imageBounds);
  historicalOverlay.setMap(map);
}

mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


    </script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

<div id="map"></div>

<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDbO6MrlSuKnLv7Q2bmDHYERx4t3_zHrAM&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: You have mixed Google Maps Javascript code with Android/Java code. See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952593/how-to-add-my-location-button-in-google-maps

Answer (score 1):

There is no setMyLocationEnabled method on a [`google.maps.Map`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)