# How to get current location button in angular google map v3?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using angular google map https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/ . This button comes in android using setMyLocationEnabled(true). I don't know how to implement this button in angular google map.

Please help me. Any help should be appreciated. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately the google maps javascript API does not have this feature, you'll either have to use a third party library or do it yourself. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952593/how-to-add-my-location-button-in-google-maps)

Comment: Thanks @George will try that.